# how to use the Pusher corretly

Tags: php, pusher

i am trying use the Pusher but have a trouble.

i am doing so:

into PHP so:

```
$pusher = new Pusher(env("PUSHER_APP_KEY"), env("PUSHER_SECRET"), env("PUSHER_APP_ID"), array('cluster' => env("PUSHER_CLUSTER")));
$pusher->trigger('buy', 'compra-paga', [
                                            "id"=>$external_reference,
                                            "status"=>$status
                                        ]
);
```

it gear the follow out (example):

```
Pusher : : [
             "Event recd",
             {
               "event":"compra-paga",
               "channel":"buy",
               "data": {
                         "id":18,
                         "status":"approved"
               }
             }
]
```

In the front end (JS) i have the follow:

```
var key = "my_key";

var id_buy = localStorage.getItem("id_buy");

console.log(id_buy);
var pusher = new Pusher(key, {
    cluster: 'us2'
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('buy');

channel.bind("compra-paga", function(data) {   
    
    console.log(
                id_buy,
                jQuery.parseJSON(data),
                data,
                data.id
    ); 
    
    var id = localStorage.getItem("id_buy")

    if (id ===  data.id)
       $("#pgto").html('<h1 class="midiArea">Recebemos seu pagamento!</h1>');
       
});
```

the problem:

no one **console.log** works.

it appears that nothing out int screem.

Comment: it shows also the error: Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Clearly `data` is not what you expect, why don't you debug and `console.log(data)`...

Comment: console.log(
        id ===  data.id,
        id,
        data.id
    );

output: false, 23,23

Comment: So `data` is already an object, no need to parse it

Comment: i has get.. Thnk you. it was the return form